# VB code to print a file from a third-party application to a network drive without dialogue box

Tags: excel, pdf, printing, vb6

I have a specific requirement in our organization.

We are using a third-party tool to convert excel to pdf. Our excel files contain financial data and charts and the tool converts them to pdf files. Once converted, they are sent for printing.

Now I need to write a vb code which tampers with the printer configuration. After conversion to pdf, when I click on print in the tool, it should not go to default printer to print the physical file, nor should it display the dialog box asking for printer to choose, rather it should pop-up a custom dialog box indicating file being saved in the network drive. The drive and file name should be pre-configured.

**I know there are quite a few solutions which caters to this problem of saving a file without displaying the default dialog box** but my problem is, I am not printing files from the same application. Files are prepared by a third-party application and print option is pressed from here itself. When the file leaves for printing, I want my code to take effect. In a way, if this application is configured in a computer, no matter which tool you are using to print, the files should get saved to a network drive without popping up the default print dialogue box.

Thanks in advance. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to monitor the print spool and go from there. Taking away the user's ability to print to an actual printer and "tamper" with the system's configuration is probably not a good idea though.  [Reference here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162861.aspx)

Comment: Hiding to nothing this. Get the third party app changed or ditch it. Something like CutePDF would be the way to go.

Comment: Do you want to stop the document from being printed, or do both print and save file?? I am unsure why you aren't just using Adobe and using print to PDF inside of excel, it seems that it would satisfy all of your conditions exactly as you have requested. Or if you install Adobe, it won't avoid the print dialogue, but it will just save a pdf of anything you print to it.